# unresolved external symbol on user code

Tags: c, linker, msys

*There are plenty of questions about this link error, but most of it about undefined methods or missing lib files.*

I'm trying to compile nginx with my custom module on Windows. I used MSYS with nlink, I set up all environment etc, so nginx without my module compiles and run ok. For some reason I used xxHash algorithm, and I wanted to compile it from source just-in-time, when my module compiles. So I put xxHash folder with its source in subfolder of solution and put `#include "xxhash/xxhash.h"`. It works well when I build standalone test app from VS 2013. However when I do so from nmake, I get linker error

> ngx_http_imagick_module.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol _XXH32 referenced in function _RunJob ngx_modules.obj : error
>   LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ngx_http_imagick_module
>   objs/nginx.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

My questions:

Why method `XXH32` called external at all if it built from source and not statically linked?

Isn't `#include` directive put physical text from file in place where directive was placed? If so, how it can be that linker searches this symbol somewhere? If *not* so, shouldn't compiler create something like xxhash.obj? Because I don't see anything similar in compiler log, but I see `cl -c -O2  -W4 -nologo -MT -Zi -DFD_SETSIZE=1024 -I "C:/msys/1.0/home/tommi/imagick"  -I src/core  -I src/event  -I src/event/modules  -I src/os/win32  -I objs/lib/pcre  -I objs/lib/zlib  -I objs  -I src/http  -I src/http/modules  -I src/mail  -Foobjs/addon/ngx_http_imagick_module/ngx_http_imagick_module.obj  ../ngx_http_imagick_module/ngx_http_imagick_module.c`?

Should I compile xxHash separately to static lib in order to get this work? It's not a big deal, but I prefer to investigate this issue in order to not face it again later.

Not sure if this relevant, but xxhash has this preprocessor directive in its header:

```
#if defined (__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif
```

Can this be reason? If so, how to solve it and why/how VS does this automatically?

Comment: Did your nmake include compiling the source file that defines this method, and linking it to the target?

Comment: As I said, I don't see any entries of xxhash.c or xxhash.obj in compiler log.

Comment: well, if it's built from source as you say, then the corresponding object file should be linked into the target.

Comment: Ok, how to investigate why it's not built while source clearly does `#include` it? If it somehow not found or incorrect, why compiler not stops with error?

Comment: I think there is an option in MSVC to export the makefile, could you do that and have a look at it?

Comment: @Ashalynd looks like not anymore: `As far as I know, the "export makefile" option has been removed since VS 7.0.` from [here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?521751-Exporting-a-makefile-from-VS-2010)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870533/where-can-i-find-a-tool-to-convert-a-vs-solution-to-a-gcc-makefile

Comment: Well, answers involves Wine (I don't have any Linux machine now), "make-it-so" tool, which supports VS 2008 and 2010 (my version is 2013) and two more tools, one supported VS2010 and second which probably not works, as said in comments.

Comment: Note: I just add test.h/test.c with one empty `void test() {}` included it and comment out xxhash; I fall into the same issue, but with symbol `_test`. Now it looks like expected behavior for me. The only problem I don't know how to overcome it.

Comment: Ok, it looks like I should explicitly pass every .c file to cl.exe input in order to get .obj files. This looks strange for me if I already have precompiler directives to include all in one .obj. In my case I added it to module config file.